# How transform listview static in dynamic using json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile

Using long polling i update my jquery mobile listview, but i I wrote static code in this way to update the listview:

```
 function updatePage() {
      if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {

             var parsobj = jQuery.parseJSON( ajaxRequest.responseText );
             console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            $("#nameobj1").empty().append(parsobj.nameobj0);
            $("#prezzoobj1").empty().append(parsobj.prezzoobj0);
            $("#nameobj2").empty().append(parsobj.nameobj1);
            $("#prezzoobj2").empty().append(parsobj.prezzoobj1);
            $("#nameobj3").empty().append(parsobj.nameobj2);
            $("#prezzoobj3").empty().append(parsobj.prezzoobj2);
            $("#nameobj4").empty().append(parsobj.nameobj3);
            $("#prezzoobj4").empty().append(parsobj.prezzoobj3);
            $("#nameobj5").empty().append(parsobj.nameobj4);
            $("#prezzoobj5").empty().append(parsobj.prezzoobj4);
            makeAjaxRequest();
      }
  }
  function makeAjaxRequest() {
      var datashowobj= {'type':"show-obj" };
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
      ajaxRequest.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/asta/ServletObjects", true);
      ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      ajaxRequest.send( JSON.stringify(datashowobj));
   }
```

the server send this json {"nameobj0":"w","prezzobj0":1.0, nameobj1:"x", "prezzobj2":60.0 ...  }

and the li tag that I want put in the listview is the following 
     `

```
      <li><h3 id = "nameobj1"></h3> 
      <p id="prezzoobj1"></p>
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
   <select>
    <option>$</option>
    <option>€</option>
    <option>£</option>
    <option>¥</option>
    <option>₩</option>
    <option>₹</option>
   </select>
   <input id="currency-controlgroup1" type="text" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-  textinput ui-btn">
  <button id="bo1" class ="myclass" data-icon="plus">Piazza l'offerta</button>
  <div id="piaz1"></div> 

  </div>
     </li>`
```

I thank you for the answers I hope I can have an example of how to achieve .

Comment: not sure what you mean. Try refreshing the list. $("#myisview").listview("refresh")

Answer (score 0):

```
var parsobj = jQuery.parseJSON( ajaxRequest.responseText );
for (var id in parsobj)
{
    if ($("#"+id).length>0)  //check if exists an element with this id
        $("#"+id).empty().append(parsobj[id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML markup, just create an empty list:

```
<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
```

Change your returned JSON into an array of jSON objects where each item in the array is the data for one listitem in the listview e.g.:

```
var parsobj =[
    {"nameobj":"w","prezzobj":1.0}, 
    {"nameobj":"x", "prezzobj":60.0},
    {"nameobj":"y","prezzobj":11.0},
    {"nameobj":"z","prezzobj":58.0}    
];
```

Then in your updatePage() code, iterate the array and create a listitem for each member of the array. Append these to the listview, tell jQM to refresh the listview and to enhance all child controls:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < parsobj.length; i++){
    html += '<li>';
    html += '<h3>' + parsobj[i].nameobj + '</h3>';
    html += '<p>' + parsobj[i].prezzobj + '</p>';        
    html += '<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true"><select><option>$</option><option>€</option> <option>£</option><option>¥</option><option>₩</option><option>₹</option></select>';
    html += '<input id="currency-controlgroup' + i +'" type="text" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" />';
    html += '<button id="bo' + i +'" class ="myclass" data-icon="plus">Piazza l\'offerta</button>';
    html += '<div id="piaz' + i +'"></div></div>';
    html += '</li>';
}

//empty the listview, append new items and tell jQM to refresh
$("#mylist").empty().append(html).listview("refresh").enhanceWithin();
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bLx41ff9/2/)**